# erro: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Value must be an array in multiple-selection mode

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

Faendo um compareWith, com a finalidade de quando eu editar, as dropdowns já possa vir preenchida com os valores atribuídos. Ao fazer isso, eu pego esse erro:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Value must be an array in
>   multiple-selection mode.

Sinceramente não sei de onde ele pede esse **array** conforme diz o erro. Eis minha **html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <caption>
                Lista de Aplicabilidades
                <div class="float-right">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onCreate()" value="+">
                </div>
            </caption>
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Contexto</th>
                    <th>Tipo de Pagamento</th>
                    <th>Tipo de Entrega</th>
                    <th>MarketPlace</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let aplicabilidade of dataSource" [formGroup]="createForm">
                    <td>
                        <input formControlName="id" type="hidden">
                        <label *ngIf="aplicabilidade.edit != true">{{ aplicabilidade.name }}</label>
                        <label *ngIf="aplicabilidade.edit === true"><input formControlName="name" type="text"></label>
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <label *ngIf="aplicabilidade.edit != true">{{ aplicabilidade.context }}</label>
                        <label *ngIf="aplicabilidade.edit === true"><input formControlName="context" type="text"></label>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <input formControlName="id" type="hidden">
                        <label *ngIf="aplicabilidade.edit != true">{{ aplicabilidade.typePaymentDetailsModels }}</label>
                        <label *ngIf="aplicabilidade.edit === true">
                                <mat-form-field>
                                    <mat-select multiple [compareWith]="compareValues" 
                                        formControlName="typePaymentDetailsModel" 
                                        placeholder="Tipo de Pagamento" name="payment" >
                                        <mat-option  *ngFor="let payment of dataSourcePayment" [value]="payment.id">   
                                        {{payment.name}}            
                                        </mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                </mat-form-field>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <label *ngIf="aplicabilidade.edit != true">{{ aplicabilidade.typeDeliveryDetailsModels }}</label>
                        <label *ngIf="aplicabilidade.edit === true">
                            <!-- <input formControlName="typeDeliveryDetailsModels" type="text"> -->

                        </label>
                    </td>

                    <td> 
                        <label *ngIf="aplicabilidade.edit != true">{{ aplicabilidade.marketPlace }}</label>
                        <label *ngIf="aplicabilidade.edit === true"><input formControlName="marketPlace" type="text"></label>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <fa *ngIf="checkEdit()" name="pencil" (click)="initEditAplicabilidade(aplicabilidade)"></fa>
                        <fa *ngIf="aplicabilidade.edit === true" name="save" (click)="onUpdate()"></fa>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <fa *ngIf="checkEdit()" name="times" (click)="onDelete(aplicabilidade)"></fa>
                        <fa *ngIf="aplicabilidade.edit === true" name="ban" (click)="aplicabilidade.edit = null; initDefaultForm();"></fa>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Essa é minha **Component**. Postei toda ela, mas é o método compareValues

```
export class ApplicabilityComponent implements OnInit {

  createForm: FormGroup;
  public dataSource: Model.ApplicabilityItem[];
  public dataSourcePayment: Model.TypePaymentItem[];
  public dataSourceDelivery: Model.TypeDeliveryItem[];
  public form:any;

  constructor(private _applicabilityService: ApplicabilityService, 
              private builder: FormBuilder, 
              private route: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onGet();
    this.initDefaultForm();    
  }

  initDefaultForm() {
    this.createForm = this.builder.group({
      id: '',
      name: '',
      context: '',
      typeDeliveryDetailsModels: [],
      typePaymentDetailsModel: [],
      marketPlace: false
    });
  }

  onCreate(){
    this.route.navigate(['create-aplicability']);
  }

  onDelete(aplicabilidade: Model.ApplicabilityItem) {
    if (confirm('Deseja excluir o operador: ' + aplicabilidade.name + '?')) {

      this._applicabilityService
        .delete<any>(aplicabilidade.id)
        .subscribe((res) => {
          this.onGet();
        });
    }
  }

  onGet(){
    this._applicabilityService
      .getAllAplicability<Model.Result<Model.ApplicabilityItem>>()
      .subscribe((data: Model.Result<Model.ApplicabilityItem>) =>{
        this.dataSource = data.itens;
      });

      this._applicabilityService
      .getAllDelivery<Model.Result<Model.TypeDeliveryItem>>()
      .subscribe((data: Model.Result<Model.TypeDeliveryItem>) => {
      this.dataSourceDelivery = data.itens;
    }); 

    this._applicabilityService
    .getAllPayment<Model.Result<Model.TypePaymentItem>>()
    .subscribe((data: Model.Result<Model.TypePaymentItem>) => {
      this.dataSourcePayment = data.itens;
    });

  }

  initEditAplicabilidade(aplicabilidade: any){
    aplicabilidade.edit = true;
    this.createForm = this.builder.group({
      id: aplicabilidade.id,
      name: aplicabilidade.name,
      context: aplicabilidade.context,
      typeDeliveryDetailsModels: aplicabilidade.typeDeliveryDetailsModels,
      typePaymentDetailsModel: aplicabilidade.typePaymentDetailsModels,
      marketPlace: aplicabilidade.marketPlace
    });
  }

  checkEdit() {
    if (this.dataSource == null || this.dataSource.length == 0) return false;
      return this.dataSource.filter((item: any) => item.edit === true).length == 0;
  }

  onUpdate(){
    let formValue = this.createForm.value;
    this._applicabilityService.update<Model.Result<Model.ApplicabilityItem>>(formValue)
    .subscribe(success =>{
        this.onGet();
      },
        error =>{
      } 
    );
  }

  compareValues(c1: Model.TypePaymentItem, c2: Model.TypePaymentItem): boolean{
    debugger;
    return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2;
  }
}
```

e minha model

```
export interface ApplicabilityItem{
        id: string,
        name: string,
        context: string,
        typePaymentDetailsModels: TypePaymentItem,
        typeDeliveryDetailsModels: TypeDeliveryItem,
        marketPlace: boolean
    }

    export interface TypePaymentItem{
        id: string,
        sgpTypePaymentId: number,
        name: string
    }

    export interface TypeDeliveryItem{
        id: string,
        sgpTypeDeliveryId: number,
        name: string
    }
```

O que estou errando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como a própria documentação diz:

> #### Error: Value must be an array in multiple-selection mode
>
> This error is thrown if you attempt to assign a value other than `null`, `undefined`, or an array to a `<mat-select multiple>`. For example, something like `mySelect.value = 'option1'`. What you likely meant to do was `mySelect.value = ['option1']`.

Traduzindo à google tradutor:

> #### Erro: o valor deve ser uma matriz no modo de seleção múltipla
>
> Este erro é lançada se você tentar atribuir um valor diferente de `null`, `undefined`, ou uma matriz para uma `<mat-select multiple>`. Por exemplo, algo como `mySelect.value = 'option1'`. O que você provavelmente quis fazer foi `mySelect.value = ['option1']`.

Verifique os valores retornados dos seus serviços (`console.log`), em algum deles, o retorno, provavelmente não é uma das opções válidas

**Edit:**

A solução é definir o valor na criação do `FormGroup`

```
initEditAplicabilidade(aplicabilidade: any){
    aplicabilidade.edit = true;
    this.createForm = this.builder.group({
      id: aplicabilidade.id,
      name: aplicabilidade.name,
      context: aplicabilidade.context,
      typeDeliveryDetailsModels: [aplicabilidade.typeDeliveryDetailsModels],
      typePaymentDetailsModel: [aplicabilidade.typePaymentDetailsModels],
      marketPlace: aplicabilidade.marketPlace
    });
}
```

No `FormGroup.group` você deve passar um objeto com chave sendo o nome e o valor sendo um array contendo o valor e as validações, por exemplo:

```
{
    nomeDoInput: ['Primeiro passe o valor do campo', [Validators.required,  Validators.pattern(/minha regexp/)]]
}
```

Se usar apenas uma validação, por exemplo, apenas `Validators.required`, pode passar sem estar dentro de um array:

```
{
    nomeDoInput: ['Primeiro passe o valor do campo', Validators.required]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi e não entendi até agora porque não funcionou como está. Com a ajuda de um colega, fiz isso no meu Form do lado Angular(Component). Foi uma solução, com cara de gambi, mas foi o que resolveu. Vou testar pela resposta do Guilherme Costamilan. Eu fiz um get no "array" de payment e delivery e depois atribuí o novo valor, conforme abaixo.

```
initEditAplicabilidade(aplicabilidade: any){
    aplicabilidade.edit = true;
    this.createForm = this.builder.group({
      id: aplicabilidade.id,
      name: aplicabilidade.name,
      context: aplicabilidade.context,
      typeDeliveryDetailsModels: [],
      typePaymentDetailsModel: [],
      marketPlace: aplicabilidade.marketPlace
    });

    this.createForm.get('typePaymentDetailsModel').setValue(aplicabilidade.typePaymentDetailsModels);
    this.createForm.get('typeDeliveryDetailsModels').setValue(aplicabilidade.typeDeliveryDetailsModels);
  }
```

Comment: Tenta colocar dessa forma: `... this.builder.group({ ... typeDeliveryDetailsModels: [aplicabilidade.typePaymentDetailsModels], typePaymentDetailsModel: [aplicabilidade.typeDeliveryDetailsModels], ...` funciona?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam, cara dessa forma funcionou e era bem simples e não vimos a resposta. Tentamos de várias formas e acredite, menos dessa forma. Acho essa abordagem mais limpa e sem cara de gambi. Valeu!!! Se postar ou editar sua resposta, prefiro marcar a sua do que a minha, que é mais gambi.

Comment: Como preferir, editei a minha resposta com uma breve explicação